# Firefox rendering of background image

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, cover

I have a problem when using a cover page on my website. The coverpage, a page consisting of an image covering the whole browser window, is loaded correctly in all browsers but when I scroll down and then up again the image is distorted(only when using firefox). The easiest way to explain is just to show the website: http://arkad.tlth.se . The CSS for the background image is the following:

```
.site-wrapper-inner {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: url(http://arkad.tlth.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cover-image.jpg) no-repeat center fixed transparent;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

If you want more information on the code, please inspect element. I tried using this instead which worked but now the scrolling effect is gone. The effect that the background image is scrolled over by the other content. I tried to combine the two which makes the whole screen become blanc. Is there something I'm missing?

```
background: url("http://lewisking.net/images/header-image.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0px 100% / cover transparent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to confirm that the problem appears in Firefox.  The background image displays correctly in Chrome.

The problem in Firefox disappears if you change `display: table-cell` to `display: block`.

I suspect that Firefox's table cell height computation engine is causing the problem.

I would try some other display mode other than table-cell.

I tried using `display: table` with `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`, which is close to
what you need.  Some trial and error may be required.

I was able to reproduce the problem as shown below (table cells show the drawing problem).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
 background: url(http://placekitten.com/2000/2000) no-repeat center fixed transparent;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}
div.bg-cell {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 400px;
  width: 1000px; /* the width is for demo only... */
}
div.bg-block {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  display: table; /* block also works... */
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-cell"></div>
<div class="bg-block"></div>
```

Comment: setting display:table, height: 100% and width: 100% worked! There where some other things that changed places but I'm sure those are easier to fix, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.site-wrapper {
 display: block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: url(http://arkad.tlth.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cover-image.jpg) no-repeat center fixed transparent;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

And remove the '.site-wrapper-inner' rule.

Comment: The culprit seems to be `display: table-cell`.  Depending on the layout design, there are a few possible solutions.  I am not sure why the problem is specific to Firefox.  Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: It is tempting to use the display: table, display:table-cell properties. However, in my experience they are problematic and should be avoided.

Comment: I think the wisdom of the craft is knowing when to use certain elements to get the desired result. All the best!